# how to access related table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have some related models. A `user` can belong to many `group`s and `group`s can have any number of `siteCensus`es. I want to run a query but limit the results to only those siteCensus that he is allowed to see. In order to do that, I have to know if a given `id` is in the list of a `user`'s `siteCensus`es. The models and tables are named predictably.

I've tried to set a relation like this:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->hasManyThrough('App\SiteCensus', 'App\GroupSiteCensus', 'group_id','id',,'sites_census_id')
```

but no luck. Another thing I tried is this:

`$user->load('groups.siteCensus')`

which does get me a list of all the `siteCensus`es, but I can't easily extract just the `id` fields to check for membership.

Ultimately, I need to plug it into the model like this:

```
Class Patient extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope('status', function (Builder $builder) {
                $site_census_ids = .......
                $builder->where(function (Builder $q) use ($site_census_ids) {
                    return $q->whereIn('sites_census_id', $site_census_ids);
                });    
        });
    }
}
```

Some relevant code is below:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\User");
    }

    public function siteCensus()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\SiteCensus", 'group_site_census', 'group_id', 'sites_census_id');
    }

}
```

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
    }
}
```

```
class SiteCensus extends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany("App\Group");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `polymorphic relationship` .

Comment: I'm not sure how a polymorphic relationship answers this relation. A user can have many groups and groups have many users; groups can have many sitecensus and sitecensus can belong to many groups. But.... a sitecensus can't have any users (at least not directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly .. you want $site_census_ids that the user have
simple enough:

```
$site_census_ids=$myUser->groups()
->join('group_site_census','group_site_census.group_id','=','groups.id')
->join('sites_census','sites_census.id','group_site_census.sites_census_id')
->select('sites_census.id')->get()->pluck('id');
```

please make sure the table names 'sites_census','groups' are correct

Comment: That's a good start, but what I need is a list of siteCensus that the user can access. Let me modify the question a bit so I can be clearer

Comment: i have edit my answer ... please let me know if it helps

Comment: Your answer got me where I needed to go, even though I didn't really ask it very well. My answer below is what I ended up using. I didn't know that whereHas() could take a compound table expression.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that laravel actually does have an easy way to do this. You can use `whereHas()` with linked tables directly. In my case, this is what I needed.

```
        static::addGlobalScope('status', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where(function (Builder $q) {
                    return $q->whereHas('siteCensus.groups.users', function ($q) {
                            $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                        });
                });
        });
```